# Executing SSIS package as SQL Job Agent failed - returns DTSER_FAILURE (1)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-agent-job

In this  Job -  SSIS is used  for converting a table data into excel file . It is converting the table data into  excel file successfully  but still it is showing as Job failed .

The following is the message shown in job history

**Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.1600.22 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:30:26 AM  Error: 2014-05-01 04:30:33.68     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - po_list_tmp [79]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  End Error  Error: 2014-05-01 04:30:33.68     Code: 0xC0209029     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - po_list_tmp [79]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input" (90)" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (90)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2014-05-01 04:30:33.68     Code: 0xC0047022     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - po_list_tmp" (79) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (90). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  Error: 2014-05-01 04:30:33.69     Code: 0xC02020C4     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - po_list_tmp [1]     Description: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.  End Error  Error: 2014-05-01 04:30:33.70     Code: 0xC0047038     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - po_list_tmp" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:30:26 AM  Finished: 4:30:34 AM  Elapsed:  8.627 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.**

What is the root cause for this error? How it can be rectified?

Comment: (1) First of all, does the error happen if the SSIS package is run standalone (not in a job)?  (2) To see which column is column "90", from the message `The "input "Destination Input" (90)" failed`, follow the directions at this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/260151a1-3deb-4d3c-a042-2087ab73982f/datalfow-error-detination-input-failed-with-error-code-0xc020907b?forum=sqlintegrationservices